# How to get Grid's current State i.e. sorting, grouping, column add , removed

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using Extjs 4.1

I want to know , How will I get grids current state after user has done any opration.

i.e. After Grid gets rendere.. user may do sorting, adding or removing any column, Or he can move the column as well

I want to know How will I get to know , if user has done any changes i.e. sorting etc ..

Answer (score 1):

```
listeners: {
    selectionchange: function(model, records) {
        alert("selectionchange")
    }, sortchange: function(model, records) {
        alert("sortchange");
    }, columnhide: function( ct, column, eOpts ) {
        alert("columnhide");
    }, columnshow: function( ct, column, eOpts ) {
        alert("columnshow");
    }, columnmove: function( ct, column, eOpts ) {
        alert("columnmove");
    }                               
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..

Comment: These are the events fired when sorting, grouping, column add , removed . But still i don't have clue to how to get the current visible columns , how sorting is applied and how filters are applied. I have a specific requirement where i need to get the current state of the grid and create a excel file on basis of that. Anyone can give a code sample would be appreciated

Comment: Although somewhat uninformative, this snippet was still useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there are any events defined for sorting, so you would need to extend the store, and override the sort method for that.  For the columns though, they have a beforeshow and beforehide method that you could set listeners to track.

---

```
//Define something like this
Ext.define('Ext.ux.data.Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    sort: function () {
        //Fire Event to notify of change
        this.fireEvent('beforesort', this, this.sorters);

        //Call parent sort function
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

//Then use it like so
Ext.define('MyApp.stores.StoreName', {
    fields:[....],
    proxy: {...},
});

var store = Ext.create('MyApp.stores.StoreName');

store.on('beforesort', trackSorting);

//Tracking function
function trackSorting(store, sorters) {
    //store or use them however you want here
}

//And create a grid
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Pane', {
    title: 'Test',
    columns: [...],
    store: store
});

//And listen to the columns show/hide events
for (var i = 0, l = grid.columns.length; i < l; i++) {
    grid.columns[i].on({
        beforeshow: beforeShowColumn,
        beforehide: beforeHideColumn
    })
}

//Column tracking information
function beforeShowColumn(column, eOpts) {
    //Note that it's gone somewhere
}
function beforeHideColumn(column, eOpts) {
    //Note that it's back somewhere
}
```

Comment: Is there any event or method , to get latest Grid's config i.e. if user removed any one or two columns , then I should get in grid.columns= only those columns which are currently displayed to screen. Can you please suggest ?